# convert a heif file to png/jpg using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, heic, heif

The use case is very straight forward. Imagemagick is able to do the conversion but I want to do it with ffmpeg. Here is the all commands I have tried and all of them gives moov atom not found error.

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/ajitesh/Downloads/sample1.heif -c:v png -pix_fmt rgb48 /Users/ajitesh/Downloads/sample.png
```

Output

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f85aa813200] moov atom not found
/Users/ajitesh/Downloads/sample1.heif: Invalid data found when processing input
```

it seems like moov atom is actually not present by trying to extract the location of moov atom using the following command

```
ffmpeg -v trace -i /Users/ajitesh/Downloads/sample1.heif 2>&1 | grep -e type:\'mdat\' -e type:\'moov\'
```

Output

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f824c00f000] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 2503083 420 2503495
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f824c00f000] type:'mdat' parent:'root' sz: 2503083 420 2503495
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

FFmpeg does not currently support HEIF decoding (as of 2021-01-11).

Check the bug report [#6521: HEIF support](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6521) as FFmpeg development is active and the situation may change in the future.

Comment: For those of you who just want a command to convert files, I recommend `sips` on MacOS. https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410920

Answer (score 9):

Welp, it's 2023 and ffmpeg still doesn't support the `heif` image format. I recommend using `heif-convert`, which is available via all major linux package managers and homebrew.

Here are the instructions to install and use `heif-convert` on major Linux distributions and macOS. It's usage looks like this:

```bash
heif-convert input.[heic|heif] output.[png|jpg]
```

And you can install it via:

1. **Ubuntu/Debian:**

```bash
sudo apt-get install libheif1
```

2. **Fedora:**

```bash
sudo dnf install libheif
```

3. **RHEL/CentOS:**

```bash
sudo yum install epel-release libheif
```

4. **Arch Linux:**

```bash
sudo pacman -S libheif
```

5. **openSUSE:**

```bash
sudo zypper install libheif1
```

6. **macOS:**

```bash
brew install libheif
```

Comment: please update ubuntu, `Command 'heif-convert' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install libheif-examples`

Comment: WSL works like a charm.